# How can I remove the google recaptcha from a JavaScript form?

Tags: javascript, forms, recaptcha

How can I remove the google recaptcha ?
This is my code for a form.

```
// On  focusing the form elements
$('.subject').on('focus', function() {
    // Check the user if logged in or not
    if( loginStatus !== 'logged' )  {
        loginAlert();
    }

});

// On clicking the submit button
$('.create-ticket-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Check the user if logged in or not
    if( loginStatus !== 'logged' )  {
        // If not logged in, then alert them.
        loginAlert();
    } else {

        // Initialize variables
        var route= $('#createTicket').attr('action'),
            data = new FormData( $("#createTicket")[0] ),
            subject = $('.subject').val(),
            department = $('.department').val(),
            message = $('.message').val(),
            valid = '';

        // Check if the message length is less than or equal to 10
        if( ! message) {
            valid = 'invalid';
            $('.form-status').removeClass('alert').html(' ');
            $('.message-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error').find('.help- 
       block').html('<strong> Message </strong> is required');
        } else {
            valid = '';
            $('.message-group').removeClass('has-error').find('.help-block').html(' ');
        }

        // Check if the department is selected
        if( ! department ) {
            valid = 'invalid';
            $('.form-status').removeClass('alert').html(' ');
            $('.department-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error').find('.help- 
         block').html('<strong> Support Department </strong> is required');
        } else {
            valid = '';
            $('.department-group').removeClass('has-error').find('.help-block').html(' ');
        }

        // Check if the subject length is less than or equal to 3
        if(subject.length <= 3) {
            valid = 'invalid';
            $('.form-status').removeClass('alert').html(' ');
            $('.subject-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error').find('.help- 
      block').html(' <strong> Subject </strong> is required');
        } else {
            valid = '';
            $('.subject-group').removeClass('has-error').find('.help-block').html(' ');
        }

        if( valid == '') {
            captcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            if( captcha.length == 0 ) {
                $('.form-status').removeClass('alert-warning').addClass('animated fadeInUp alert 
         alert-warning').html(' Please complete the recaptcha. ');
            } else {
                $('.form-status').removeClass('alert-danger').html(' ');

                // Perform the AJAX Ticket Creating Submission
                ajaxTicketCreate(route, data);
            }

        }
    }

    /*----------  Ajax Ticket Creation  ----------*/

    function ajaxTicketCreate(route, data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: route,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.form-status').removeClass('alert-warning').addClass('animated fadeInUp alert 
       alert-info').html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i> Processing data...');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                 $('.form-status').removeClass('alert-warning alert-info').addClass('animated 
            fadeInUp alert alert-success').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Your ticket has been 
               submitted.');

                 // Reset the form
                 $("#createTicket")[0].reset();
                 $('.ticket-submit-file label span').html('<span class="browse">Browse</span> your 
                   file here…');
                 grecaptcha.reset();
            },
            error: function(data) {

                var errMsg = '';

                var errors = (data.responseJSON);

                $.each(errors, function(index, value){

                    errMsg += '<li>'+ value +'</li>';

                });

                $('.form-status').removeClass('alert-success').addClass('animated fadeInUp alert 
              alert-warning').html( errMsg );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I click on submit button it says please complete the recaptcha , I want to remove the recaptcha from the code, when I remove the recapcha from the code it still says please complete it so I don't want this recaptcha. How do I remove this bug?

Comment: `grecaptcha.reset();` under `// Reset the form` ?

Comment: You need to remove the captcha validation from the server-side code, in the URL that's in `route`.

Comment: in the route it is like this :// Ticket Route
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

 Route::post('create-tickets', [
  'as' => 'create.ticket', 
  'uses' => 'TicketController@createTicket'
 ]);

Comment: i checked the ticketcontroller also i couldnt find anything about grecaptcha

Comment: public function createTicket(Requests\CreateTicketRequest $request)
    {

        // Check the request type
        if( $request->ajax() ) :

            $ticket = \Auth::user()->tickets()->create($request->only(
                'subject', 
                'department_id', 
                'message'
            ));

            // Process the file
            $this->processFile($request, $ticket);